# Regex: Delete words from ---comments section ---

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have in a blog many links starting with https://mywebsite.com.
I want to delete those links (but before /story1.html, /story2.html, etc, from the particular comments section

```
<!-- FLAGS1 --> <div class="cotarerField"> <div align="right">

<a href="https://mywebsite.com/story1.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ro.jpg" title="ro" alt="ro" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/fr/story2.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_fr.jpg" title="fr" alt="fr" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/story3.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_en.jpg" title="en" alt="en" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/es/story4.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_es.jpg" title="es" alt="es" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/pt/story5.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_pt.jpg" title="pt" alt="pt" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/ar/story6.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ae.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ar" alt="ar" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/zh/story7.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_zh.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="zh" alt="zh" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/hi/story8.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_hi.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="hi" alt="hi" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/de/story9.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_de.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="de" alt="de" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/ru/story10.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ru.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ru" alt="ru" /></a>
</div>
<!-- FLAGS1 -->
```

or you can check here  https://pastebin.com/Dtt3KjME

THE EXPECTED RESULT (delete all `https://mywebsite.com/` )

```
<!-- FLAGS1 --> <div class="cotarerField"> <div align="right">

<a href="story1.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ro.jpg" title="ro" alt="ro" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="fr/story2.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_fr.jpg" title="fr" alt="fr" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="en/story3.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_en.jpg" title="en" alt="en" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="es/story4.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_es.jpg" title="es" alt="es" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="pt/story5.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_pt.jpg" title="pt" alt="pt" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="ar/story6.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ae.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ar" alt="ar" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="zh/story7.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_zh.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="zh" alt="zh" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="hi/story8.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_hi.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="hi" alt="hi" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="de/story9.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_de.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="de" alt="de" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="ru/story10.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ru.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ru" alt="ru" /></a>
</div>
<!-- FLAGS1 -->
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Just Edit the topic, with the expected result

Comment: To be clear, you want to make the change ONLY between `<!-- FLAGS1 -->` and another `<!-- FLAGS1 -->`? Are there more `<!-- FLAGS1 -->` in the file?

Comment: nope, only between `<!-- FLAGS1 -->`. Notice, that is not simple. Not just a simple search and delete, it must be only those links included in those 2 comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\A[\s\S]*<!-- FLAGS1 -->|\G)(?:(?!<!-- FLAGS1 -->)[\s\S])+?\Khttps://mywebsite\.com/(?=[\s\S]*<!-- FLAGS1 -->)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                         # non capture group
  \A                        # beginning of file
  [\s\S]*                   # 0 or more any character
  <!-- FLAGS1 -->           # literally
 |                          # OR
  \G                        # restart from last match position
)                           # end group
(?:                         # non capture group (Tempered Greedy Token)
  (?!<!-- FLAGS1 -->)       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't <!-- FLAGS1 -->
  [\s\S]                    # any character
)+?                         # end group, appears 1 or more times, not greedy
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this position
https://mywebsite\.com/     # text to be removed
(?=[\s\S]*<!-- FLAGS1 -->)  # positive lookahead, make sure we have <!-- FLAGS1 -->  after
```

**Given:**

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/ru/story10.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ru.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ru" alt="ru" /></a>

<!-- FLAGS1 --> <div class="cotarerField"> <div align="right">

<a href="https://mywebsite.com/story1.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ro.jpg" title="ro" alt="ro" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/fr/story2.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_fr.jpg" title="fr" alt="fr" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
</div>

<!-- FLAGS1 -->

<a href="https://mywebsite.com/ru/story10.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ru.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ru" alt="ru" /></a>
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/ru/story10.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ru.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ru" alt="ru" /></a>

<!-- FLAGS1 --> <div class="cotarerField"> <div align="right">

<a href="story1.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ro.jpg" title="ro" alt="ro" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
<a href="fr/story2.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_fr.jpg" title="fr" alt="fr" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; 
</div>

<!-- FLAGS1 -->

<a href="https://mywebsite.com/ru/story10.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ru.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ru" alt="ru" /></a>
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: @JustMe: See my edit, now it replace only between FLAGs1 comment. Reason to use Non capture instead of capture group is this is more efficient (In case of you don't need to capture some part, of course)